# vpn connection, necessary open ports

Tags: vpn, port

When VPNing into a remote network, do application specific ports (i.e. sql server) need to be open on the firewall/server to allow the transmission of packets?

Comment: Sorry about that.  New to this.  Fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your firewall/vpn, you'll need to configure your firewall to allow VPN traffic into your LAN. If you have that connection open for everything, then you won't need to allow specific ports to be open.

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon your firewall capabilites you will as mentioned have to just allow the VPN traffic through and all traffic will flow through the vpn tunnel like you were actually sitting on the network. No other ports should need to be opened for specific services if they work correctly on your LAN. If your firewall does not support PPTP or L2TP/IPSec passthrough you might be able to use SSL over VPN which uses port 443.

Answer (score 0):

Usually no, everything will go trough the VPN tunnel.